# WPF : How to bind nested dictionary in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I have a nested dictionary.

```
Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<double, string>> MyDoubleDictionary
```

It represents the following matrix

```
4/7/2015  4/15/2015  4/21/2015
 "A1"       "A2"      "A3"        10.3
 "b1"       "b2"      "b3"        15.7
 "c1"       "c2"      "c3"        20.33
```

How to bind this dictionary to a WPF DataGrid in XAML ? I am hoping to populate its sample data using Blend.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind to specific item of your `MyDoubleDictionary` where `DateTimeKey` is a key for one of the dictionary entries you could try

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding MyDoubleDictionary.[DateTimeKey].Key}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding MyDoubleDictionary.[DateTimeKey].Value}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

You could also create a separate property `Dictionary<double, string> MyDoubleDictionaryEntry` and bind the DataGrid to that property and populate it with the entry from `MyDoubleDictionary` you want to display at that moment.

**EDIT**
I dont think I get how your data is used. Is this how you represent one from example:

```
    var MyDoubleDictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<double, string>>
{
    {new DateTime(2015,4,7), new Dictionary<double, string>() {{10.3,"A1"}, {10.3,"A2"}, {10.3,"A3"}}},
    {new DateTime(2015,4,15), new Dictionary<double, string>() {{15.7,"b1"}, {15.7,"b2"}, {15.7,"b3"}}},
    {new DateTime(2015,4,21), new Dictionary<double, string>() {{20.33,"c1"}, {20.33,"c2"}, {20.33,"c3"}}}
};
```

Not sure if you are using the best data model to bind to the datagrid. The other solution might be writing your own control to display it or changing the datatemplate to suit your needs. I

If you could give some more insight that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I added a sample data to be shown on the DataGrid, Hope it is clearer for you.

Comment: @JesonMartajaya: Can you check my edit and provide more info? Or maybe you already dealt with the problem already

Comment: Yes, your edit is right. That is how I represent the data in dictionary.